# Android In App Billing Restore Transaction

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My scenario of In App Billing implementation:
1. The Home screen shows the list of products which I am planning to sell.
2. The detail screen (Screen shown on selecting a list item in home screen) will have the option to buy that product.

My understanding is that , Restore transaction request and request to check if InAppBilling is supported will have to be done in the Home screen activity. And the remaining requests(to initiate purchase etc) should be done on detail screen activity. Is this understanding correct?

If yes, how should i modify the Dungeons example to seperate out and implement on home screen activity, the two sets of requests which i need not do every time i navigate to the detail screen activity. Will i have to create seperate instances of purchase observer and related classes in both these activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restore transactions should not be done frequently, possibly only on the app's first run (so you can restore purchases if the user reinstalled the app, etc.) You don't need it for purchasing a product.

The `BillingService` offers separate methods for requesting a purchase and restoring transactions. Just call the appropriate one from the relevant activity. You only need one purchase observer, it doesn't matter how UI/activities are structured.

Comment: i got the method that restore the Purchase. but in that method there is parameter like "Long nonce". So what is that and what the value i have gave as the nonce ?

Comment: It's a random number you generate. Check the documentation and the sample project.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov i agree with your point but have you ever done the restoring of managed products after reinstalling the app. If so please share it. what i found so far is it returns a json data which contains this purchase info. but couldn't able to find how to get that json. where can i find this data in onRestoreTransactionsResponse method. thanks

Comment: Of course, it works just fine. It is absolutely the same flow as purchasing your `onStatusChanged()` or similar method will be called when the data is received via the broadcast receiver (asynchronously, so it might take some time).

Answer (score 0):

In the Dungeons example, if you make a RESTORE_TRANSACTION request the response from the server will first call this function:

onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload)

and then:
onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,ResponseCode responseCode)