# How to do restore purchase and get whether the Product is Purchase or not?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented the in-app billing in my Android app. The code I use it as below:

oncreate method:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BillingService.class));
    System.out.println(" - - - - CHECK FOR THE PURCHASE PRODUCT - - - - ");
    BillingHelper.setCompletedHandler(mTransactionHandler);
```

Handler is:

```
 public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        System.out.println("SEE FOR THE PRODUCTS PURCHASE OR NOT");
        
        Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
        Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
        Log.i(TAG, "Item purchased is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);
        
        // For Premium Pro Purchase
        if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId == "premium_pro"){
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()){
                System.out.println("START OPENING PREMIUM_PRO_BUY CONTENT");
                myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();                 
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("PREMIUM_PRO_BUY", true); // value to store                 
                prefsEditor.commit(); 
                PREMIUM_PRO_BUY = true;
                System.out.println("NOW.. . .  PREMIUM_PRO_BUY is as PURCHASED. :-)");
                System.out.println("FINISH TO OPENING BLOCK CONTENT");
                //  showItem();
            }
        }
        
        // For Feature Upgrade Purchase
        if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId == "feature_upgrade"){
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()){
                System.out.println("START OPENING FEATURE_UPGRADE_BUY CONTENT");
                myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();                 
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("FEATURE_UPGRADE_BUY", true); // value to store                 
                prefsEditor.commit(); 
                FEATURE_UPGRADE_BUY = true;
                System.out.println("NOW.. . .  FEATURE_UPGRADE_BUY is as PURCHASED. :-)");
                System.out.println("FINISH TO OPENING BLOCK CONTENT");
                //  showItem();
            }
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
    };
};
```

And in Button click my code is:

```
//      CODE TO GET PURCHASED
        if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
            
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(getApplicationContext(), "feature_upgrade"); // MY OWN
            
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check internet and make sure that you have latest GooglePlay App in your Device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Now when I click on Restore Purchase Button, I want to see which Product is Purchase or not. So what should I have to do?

I have seen this SO question: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465738/android-in-app-billing-restore-transaction), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638665/inapp-purchase-restore-transactions-i-am-not-able-to-figure-the-code-out). But not getting which product is purchase for that user and which not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html) explains details of in-app billing and offers the "Dungeons" sample application download. Please, download the sample application and look at the `mBillingService.restoreTransactions();` function, most probably it does exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks man. I have seen that demo. But i want it to get Which Product i have purchased or which not. Well let me see it again But still need help.

Comment: It just the Function of restore the Purchase. If the Database is not initiated then user can able to get the Restore Purchase. But i want is to get the Information regarding which Product_id is purchased or nor which not.

Comment: RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request to Android Market asks for the list of purchased items, which comes one by one in `onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload)` callback. As you may see, there's `itemId` and other info you might be looking for.

Comment: @Thanks. but if i Use restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity.generateNonce()); then ?

Comment: then you are on your own. if there's a working sample, you'd better use it.

Comment: but still need your help if you can.