# How to see my bought items in google play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I've developed an app that sells items. So I buy with and google account and sell with another, for testing it.

I've made refound of some items. And now when I try to buy some of these items, google play says that I already own this item.

How can I see the items I've really bought in google play?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in my merchant account. Just need to make login with the right account.

Answer (score 1):

Use Restore transaction to get your purchased details but there are certain limits for it. you can not make call certains times of it...you can use it only on installing time or as some cases.
Also you may get help from below links,

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465738/android-in-app-billing-restore-transaction)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768347/cannot-figure-out-how-to-restore-transactions-on-in-app-purchases-in-android)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393720/how-to-do-restore-purchase-and-get-whether-the-product-is-purchase-or-not)

[Link4](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

Hope it will help you.